# First request to a webhook

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

To create a webhook, it has to pass the following validation:

1. Receive a GET request onto the webhook URL and read a specific "challenge" field from the query.
2. Send this field back to where the request comes.

Can this be implemented in an Integromat app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [verification](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/app-structure/webhooks#verification) directive for this purpose.

The code would look something like this:

```
{
    "verification": {
        "condition": "{{if(query.challenge, true, false)}}",
        "respond": {
            "status": 200,
            "type": "json",
            "body": {
                "challenge": "{{query.challenge}}"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "output": "{{body}}"
    }
}
```

It's up to you to specify the verification `condition` so that the platform will be able to tell if the incoming message is a verification request or a regular webhook payload.